# Can't use fallback. Nothing happen! function() external payable {}

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.1 <0.6.0;
contract HelloWorld {

    mapping(address => uint) public balance;
    uint public countOfInvestors = 0;
    mapping(address => uint) public time;
    event Invest(address investor, uint256 amount);
    
     function deposit() private {
        if (msg.value > 0) {
            if (balance[msg.sender] == 0) {
                countOfInvestors += 1;
            }
            balance[msg.sender] = msg.value;
            time[msg.sender] = now;
            emit Invest(msg.sender, msg.value);
        }
    }
   function() external payable {
       deposit();
   }
}
```

When i SEND SOME TRX ON CONTRACT i have no new data on tronscan, contract balance increased but not display any transaction
[image]
How to make contract should what i need?
[image]
No one events and transactions but i sent few times
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only a maximum of 2300 gas can be used on a fallback function, and your `deposit` function 100% uses more than that.

Since you used too much gas, the fallback function won’t get called.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5992/how-much-computation-can-be-done-in-a-fallback-function

Comment: Did you read my question? You didn't catch my question!

Comment: Updated for clarity. You can’t use the fallback if you use too much gas.

Comment: i think you dont know about tron development

Comment: Could you clarify what you’re trying to do?

Comment: I try design smart contract like that: users make deposit some trx and random user take all trx that was deposit)

Comment: Ok. What function are you calling? If it’s deposit that’s not how the fallback function works.

Comment: I just make transfer trx to smart contract it is not right?